# Как работать с mdb на с++?

Tags: c++, access

Доброго времени суток.
У меня возникло пару трудностей. Писала программу считывания данных с txt-файлов о студентах, их предметах и оценках, которая создает два новых файла, куда записывает их средние баллы. Теперь преподаватель сказал сделать, чтобы считывало данные из access-овских бд. 
Вопрос: можно ли это осуществить на плюсах в MVS, нужны ли для этого знания SQL? В гуглах есть похожая инфа на с# и через windows forms applications, но может есть другие варианты?
Что делать? Как быть? Может кто-нибудь знает, где почитать об этом?

Comment: посоветовал бы использовать Qt, там есть возможность работать с базами данных, в том числе mdb, знания sql нужны.

Answer (score 1):

Работать с файлами MS Access используя С++ можно.

Для этого хорошо иметь хотя бы общие представления, как устроены базы данных в MS Access.

По поводу доступа к данным, можно использовать такие технологии Microsoft, как OLE или ADO, к примеру.

Подробное руководство можно найти здесь:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc811599(v=office.12).aspx

По поводу SQL - это вопрос общий. По моему мнению, при любой работе с реляционной базой данных, SQL знать надо.